# What is 'memory leak' ? It is a performance issue or security issue?

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks

I was going through Memory leak by this [link](http://www.slideshare.net/gonzaloruizdevilla/finding-and-debugging-memory-leaks-in-javascript-with-chrome-devtools) ,But because of slides I am not able to understand.Can anybody tell me that What is memory leak with example ? and It is a performance issue or security issue ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak

Comment: It's exactly what it sounds like.

Comment: The SO tag wiki page has a lot of info: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/memory-leaks/info

Comment: Hint:http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closuresleak/index.shtml?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Often* a memory leak will lead to a crash. If you've never coded in C before try. You'll learn a lot about memory allocation and access. Fun times when you're just starting.

In C compared to some languages, you have to tell the computer when you want memory and how much. You then have to tell it when you don't want the memory. So, if you want an array for 8 chars then you have to say that you want memory for those 8 chars. If you forget to tell the computer that you don't want the memory anymore then it won't be freed. This is a *memory leak*. If you do this a lot then you can run out of memory.

```
int main()
{
    int strLength = 10;
    // Lets ask for some memory for a string
    char *str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    for (int i=0; i<strLength; i++)
    {
         str[i] = 'a' + i;
    }
    str[strLength-1] = 0;
    // This should print "abcdefghi"
    printf(str);
    // We should run this to free memory: free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

The above doesn't look so bad, but if you do it in a loop then you can start using a lot of memory quickly.

As for security: If the leak is in something like a firewall and the leak can be used to cause it to crash then it's a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

As the [wikipedia webpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) says,

> In computer science, a memory leak occurs when a computer program
>   incorrectly manages memory allocations.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) In object-oriented
>   programming, a memory leak may happen when an object is stored in
>   memory but cannot be accessed by the running code.[2](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/memory-leaks/info) A memory leak
>   has symptoms similar to a number of other problems (see below) and
>   generally can only be diagnosed by a programmer with access to the
>   program.

And the [memory-leaks tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/memory-leaks/info) in stackoverflow shows that

> A memory leak occurs when a program fails to release memory that it has allocated but is no longer using.

As per your question, if it is a security issue or a performance issue, I would say both, because once a memory leak occurs, in most of the cases the program should not be able to continue to run, and being forced halt.

According to the [memory-leaks tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/memory-leaks/info) shows, A memory leak occurs in program

> can potentially quickly result in the system being unable to allocate memory for other programs (even itself) causing poor performance and unintended faults. In some less modern environments, memory leaks have the capability to crash the system unexpectedly which can lead to other issues.

Answer (score 1):

In older software everything was fixed size, like string buffers, etc.  There were few memory leaks but there were limitations of ability.

Now most modern software manages memory in allotments.  You request a block or chunk of memory for a string or a file or whatever, and when you're done with it you give it back (usually to the operating system or whoever called you).  For example, say you need to suck in a file to process, you or your function figures out how much space is needed and a request is made for a block that big.  Or if you simply want to do something as simple as build a string by concatenating two other strings together like $new = 'old' + 'er' this allocates a small block of memory for the $new string.

So getting back to the issue of giving the memory back when you are done with it.  Newer versions of php for example have what are called reference counters which allow the software to give back the memory, even if you forget to.

But what I've seen happen in some (mostly older now) software is that if an error is encountered, and a trap is done to recover from the error, there can be a mistake in the code which forgets to give back memory that you would usually give back and this would create what is called a memory leak, or memory which is allocated, but can't be reused and so gradually builds in size as this leak is re-enacted.

In lower level code this leak can cause a program to stomp on itself or someone else close by causing a crash.

Memory leaks can cause strange errors at strange times seemingly unrelated to when the error actually occurred.  Like you might have a program running for a week doing the same thing day in and out, and suddenly it fails.

So if robustness is performance, then a memory leak is a performance issue.  If it might cause software to crash it might be a security issue.  I had a friend who broke into the main university server years ago because he discovered a program that would crash and provide a window of opportunity.